# Jquery onClick Show info?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I want to do info pane like SO. In this site when I hover the tags, an info pane is opened. Which topic Should I know. Could you give a hint about this. Or any tutorial?

Thanks.

Comment: on the mouseover event, you need to show  a tootip. There are some plugins available. Search for jQuery tool tip plugins in google

Comment: Take a look on this [article](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/ before. Take a look at it. But there is a bunch of plugins, and you can also write you're own with jQuery and mouseover...

Answer (score 2):

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h9ShH/***

***Demo 2 (with animation): http://jsfiddle.net/h9ShH/1/***

HTML:

```
<ul class="tags">
    <li class="tag" data-notice="notice 1">tag 1</li>
    <li class="tag" data-notice="notice 2">tag 2</li>
    <li class="tag" data-notice="notice 3">tag 3</li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
.notice {
  position: fixed;
}​
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.tag').hover(function (e) {
    this.notice = $('<div>')
        .addClass('notice')
        .css({
            top: $(this).offset().top + 15, 
            left: $(this).offset().left + 20
        }).text($(this).data('notice'))
        .appendTo(this);
}, function () {
    this.notice.remove();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should add a listeners to `mouseover` and `mouseout`, rather than `click`.
- You may or may not want to fetch data with AJAX when such hovering occurs.
- You may or may not want to `animate` some properties of your tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

The best plugin as far as I know is [Qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/). It's MIT licensed, beautiful, has all the configuration you could possibly need.

It can be triggered on hover or on click. And, if you want to use Ajax, it supports that too: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/ajax.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8tvDU/

Answer (score 0):

You should look around [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) especially the [show animation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/).

You just have to have a div and call the show function (`show( effect, [options], [speed], [callback] )`) with the correct parameters:

```
function runEffect()
{
  var selectedEffect = "scale";
  var options = { percent: 100 };
  $("#effect").show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback);
};

$( "#button" ).click(function()
  {
    runEffect();
    return false;
  }
);
```

```
<div class="toggler">
<div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Show</h3>
    <p>
        Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
</div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Effect</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[try this link](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/)**

I like these most as there are pure CSS based and no Javascript or jQuery required